# Using if in a array php

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement

I have an array like this

```
$cars=array("Volvo","BMW","Toyota");
```

and I use this function to verify if the car BMW is in the array

```
<?php
 $cars=array("Volvo","BMW","Toyota");
 $arrlength=count($cars);

  for($x=0;$x<$arrlength;$x++) {
      echo $cars[$x];
      echo "<br>";
      if($cars[$x]="Mercedes"){
          echo "OK ";
      }
      else
      {
          echo "NO ";
      }
}
?>
```

But the result is:

```
Volvo
OK BMW
OK Toyota
OK
```

How the result is this?

Comment: `I'm an array` Heh..

Comment: Why don't you just use PHP's built-in [in_array()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) function?

Comment: Why not use [`in_array` function](https://www.google.co.uk/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=php+in_array&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=D51TVMGODcnH8gfRhYK4Bg)?

Comment: Note that `=` is an assignment operator, `==` or `===` are comparison operators

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is down to this line:

```
if($cars[$x]="Mercedes")
```

You are not comparing but assigning instead.  You need to use a double-equal for compmarison: `==` - for your purpose.

However a much better solution would be to use [`in_array` function](https://www.google.co.uk/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=php+in_array&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=D51TVMGODcnH8gfRhYK4Bg):

```
if(in_array("Mercedes", $cars)) {
    echo "OK";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [in_array()][1] to check whether a value is found in an array.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the in_array() function http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

Answer (score 1):

The direct answer to your question is because `=` and `==` are not the same. It should be `if( $cars[$x] == "Mercedes")`

However you can avoid the problem entirely by using the appropriate built-in functions:

```
if( in_array("Mercedes",$cars)) echo "Oh look a fancy car!";
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you this function:
http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_in_array.asp

Answer (score 0):

Use `in_array()` to check whether a value is found in an array. Like so:

```
$inArray = in_array("BMW", $cars);
if ($inArray)
    echo 'OK';
```

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is that you're not using the comparison operator `==`, but instead, you are using `=` which is the operator used to assign variables, so `if($cars[$x]="Mercedes")` is always evaluating to true and therefore you're seeing OK everytime. So you have to use `==` instead

On the other hand, what you want may be accomplished in a better way, using in_array()

```
$cars=array("Volvo","BMW","Toyota");
if(in_array('Mercedes', $cars)) echo 'OK';
```

However, if you're also interested in finding out how many Mercedes' are in there, you need to do the following

```
$cars=array("Volvo","BMW","Toyota");
$cars = array_count_values($cars);
if(isset($cars['Mercedes'])) {
    echo 'There are '.$cars['Mercedes'].' mercedes in the array';
} else {
    echo 'There are no mercedes in the array.';
}
```

Comment: $cars['Mercedes'] is null here because "Mercedes" is a value and not a key

Comment: @Apolo You might wanna read up on array_count_values()

Comment: sorry, didn't saw you overwriting it. But you might wanna read up on in_array too ;-)

Comment: @Apolo you might wanna read my answer fully. :P

Comment: Wups ! My bad ! haha

Answer (score 0):

First, you are looking to every elements in your array:
for each element:

- you display the name with `echo $cars[$x];`
- return to a new line with `<br>`
- if it is a "Mercedes" you display "OK"; if it's not "NO"

BUT in fact you don't test if it is a "Mercedes" because you doesn't use a comparator sign (`==`) but an assignement sign (`=`) so it is always true.

If you only want to check if a "Mercedes" is in the array use the php function 'in_array' ([SEE DOC](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.in-array.php))

```
<?php
 $cars=array("Volvo","BMW","Toyota");
 if(in_array("Mercedes",$cars)) {
      echo "OK ";
 }
 else
 {
     echo "NO ";
 }
?>
```